# Authentication method unknown to the client in Magento 2.2.2

Tags: php, database, server-setup, magento2.2.2

Current php version 7.0.25 with which mysql version compatibility

issue:

```
3 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client
Exception #1 (PDOException): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client
Exception #2 (PDOException): PDO::__construct(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [mysql_old_password]
```